# AFNetworking 2.0 with large JSON response

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I have a program that need to call a 3rd party web service to get the JSON data.
However, I get a `nil` responseObject in success block when the response data is around 1.7 MB plain JSON text using the function `[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager GET:parameters:success:failure:]`
The function is OK if the response data is in smaller chunk.

Is there any text length limit for the iOS JSON framework to parse it?
How should I deal with this problem unless asking the 3rd party to output the data by chunk?

Comment: have the same problem, still looking for an answer but maybe you can download the entire file and then read that file.

Answer (score 1):

it may be problem slow network . so set the timeout of the request in Your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` class. and Default timeout of request is 60.

```
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];
```